# Function with no arguments works just fine, with arguments - crashes

Tags: xcode, function

it works with no problems:
h file:

```
- (BOOL) trytoGETURL;
```

m file

```
    - (BOOL) trytoGETURL {

    / some code here ... 


      if ([response statusCode] == 200)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
   }


    - (IBAction)ButtonTouchUp:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button clicked");
    if (  [self trytoGETURL]) {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    }  else    NSLog(@"problem");
```

but this crashes:
h file

```
    - (BOOL) trytoGETURL:(NSString *) baseurl Redvalue:(int)red 
GreenValue:(int)green BlueValue: (int) blue;
```

m file

```
    - (BOOL) trytoGETURL:(NSString *) baseurl Redvalue:(int)red 
GreenValue:(int)green BlueValue: (int) blue  {



   if ([response statusCode] == 200)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
   }


- (IBAction)ButtonTouchUp:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button clicked");
    if (  [self trytoGETURL:@"sd" Redvalue:100 Greenvalue:100 Bluevalue:100]) {
        NSLog(@"est takaya stranica");
    }  else    NSLog(@"net takoi stranica");
```

Xcode also writes: instance method not found!?? 
and by the way it doesn't help me with when I'm starting to write like usual, why is it so?

Comment: Have you declared `response`? From what you've posted, you haven't.

Comment: why do i need it? it works good without it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mis-interpretation on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was just a problem with suntax.
`trytoGETURL:(NSString *) baseurl` - is wrong, 
`trytoGETURL:(NSString *)baseurl` is right. - no space needed.

Answer (score 2):

Check your capitalization:

```
trytoGETURL:Redvalue:Greenvalue:Bluevalue:
```

is **most certainly** not the same as:

```
trytoGETURL:RedValue:GreenValue:BlueValue:
```